# Creating Id using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to create staffid from three different textboxes values by getting their first letter & adding auto increment number atlast.

eg "staffname", "gender", "designation" result staffid: sgd01 & I want to auto display in the staff id textbox while staffid textbox is disabled. Here is the code below:

```
<input name="staffname" id="staffname" size="30" type="text" value placeholder=" Staff Name" onkeyup="quick()" class="formTxtInput">
```

Script

```
function quick() {   

    var gender = document.getElementById('gender').value;
    var staffname = document.getElementById('staffname');
    var desg = document.getElementById('desg').value;

    var gen = gender.charAt(0);
    var sn = staffname.charAt(0);
    var dg = desg.charAt(0);

    var val = gen + sn + dg;
    document.getElementById('staffid').value = val;
}
```

Comment: I think missing `.value` it should be `document.getElementById('staffname').value`

Comment: missing `var staffname = document.getElementById('staffname').value;`

Comment: is it due to same name and id in your element. did you tried to change name= "staff_name"?
and  var staffname = document.getElementById('staffname').value is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a missing .value for var staffname. It should be

```
var staffname = document.getElementById('staffname').value;
```

Also your function needs to be called on every keyup on each of the 3 input boxes so that updated values can be processed

Here is a working sample: http://jsbin.com/vobikejejo/1/

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks for your help dear, but what about the adding number next to it. for example, stm01 how to increase 1 in every record, dug02.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by updating your function as below:

```
<script>
 var num=01;
 function quick() { 
  num+=1;
  var gender = document.getElementById('gender').value;
  var staffname = document.getElementById('staffname').value;
  var desg = document.getElementById('desg').value;
  var gen = gender.charAt(0);
  var sn = staffname.charAt(0);
  var dg = desg.charAt(0);

  var val = gen + sn + dg + num;
  document.getElementById('staffid').value = val;
}
```

By default there is no value, so it is not working. Try by setting the default value.

```
<input name="staffname" id="staffname" size="30" type="text" value="staffname" placeholder=" Staff Name" onkeyup="quick()" class="formTxtInput">
<input name="gender" id="gender" size="30" type="text" value="gender" placeholder=" Staff Name" class="formTxtInput">
<input name="desg" id="desg" size="30" type="text" value="desg" placeholder=" Staff Name"class="formTxtInput">
<input name="staffid" id="staffid" size="30" disabled="disabled" type="text" value placeholder=" Staff Name" class="formTxtInput">
```

YOu can view demo here [1](http://plnkr.co/edit/nwh9izt4EOx8fF79kaIV?p=preview)